# Hystrix timeout doesn't rollback transaction in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, transactional, hystrix

I am trying to implement hystrix with @Transactional on a method in spring boot.

```
@Transactional(transactionManager="primaryTrnsManager")
@HystrixCommand(commandKey ="createRecord", fallbackMethod="createRecordFallback", commandProperties={
@HystrixProperty(name="execution.siolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds",value="1000"),
@HystrixProperty(name="circuitBreaker.requestVoulumeThreshold",value="20"),
@HystrixProperty(name="circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds",value="5000"),
@HystrixProperty(name="circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage",value="50")})
public String createRecord(String name){
...............
//Dbcall
}
@Transactional(transactionManager="backUptranManager",propagation=propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public String createRecordFallback(){
//dbcall
```

}

What what is happeneing is when the hystrix timeout happens the call i made to database is not getting rollback and the hystrix is falling back to secondary and again calling the database with same sql query. In case of timeout, i want to abort the previous transaction and start another one. Usually @Transactional does that but with hystrix,i am inserting dubplicate records.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

This happen because the HistryxCommand is ran in a completely different thread, so, when the "Histryx Admin Thread" (the one which is watching your command thread) reaches the timeout, it's marking the command thread to be interrupted, but what happen inside of it can't be managed by Hyxtrix.

So, the best approach to reach out the behaviour that you want, is set the timeout for the transaction or even at the jdbc library level, so, the timeout will be managed from inside the command thread, if it's reached out, the Timeout Exception will be throwed from inside the command thread, and Hyxtrix will manage it properly.